# What's the neatest way to define circular lists with Scala?

Tags: scala, circular-list

Here is my attempt:

```
case class A(val a: A, val b: Int){
    override def toString() = b.toString
}

lazy val x: A = A(y, 0)
lazy val y: A = A(z, 1)
lazy val z: A = A(x, 2)
```

The problem comes when trying to do anything with x; causing x to be evaluated starts off a circular evaluation going through x, y, z and ends in a stack overflow. Is there a way of specifying that val a should be computed lazily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `A.a`  itself lazy.
You can do it by turning it into a by name parameter that is used to initialize a lazy field:

```
class A(a0: => A, val b: Int){
  lazy val a = a0
  override def toString() = b.toString
}
object A {
  def apply( a0: => A, b: Int ) = new A( a0, b )
}
```

You could also do the same using a helper class `Lazy`:

```
implicit class Lazy[T]( getValue: => T ) extends Proxy {
  def apply(): T = value
  lazy val value = getValue
  def self = value
}
```

It has the advantage that you code is pretty much unchanged except for changing `a: A` into `a: Lazy[A]`:

```
case class A(val a: Lazy[A], val b: Int){
 override def toString() = b.toString
}
```

Note that to access the actual value wrapped in `Lazy`, you can either use `apply` or `value` (as in `x.a()` or `x.a.value`)

Comment: +1 for the Proxy example; that's quite sexy. Any drawbacks to this method? On top of that, how does equality behave for class A?

Comment: Probably the most prominent one is that it requires an additional instance just for making your field lazy. 
The first (manual) solution uses a standard lazy val, and those ones only require one bit (as opposed to aful object) per value.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `Stream` like this:

```
lazy val stream: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: 2 #:: stream

stream.take(10).toList
// List(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0)
```

In general you should use `call-by-name` parameters:

```
class A(_a: => A, val b: Int) {
    lazy val a = _a
    override def toString() = s"A($b)"
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

lazy val x: A = new A(y, 0)
lazy val y: A = new A(z, 1)
lazy val z: A = new A(x, 2)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

x: A = <lazy>
y: A = <lazy>
z: A = <lazy>

scala> z.a.a.a.a.a
res0: A = A(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a lazy circular list using the `Stream` data type:

```
lazy val circular: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: 3 #:: circular
```

You can do the same trick on your own with by-name parameters:

```
class A(head: Int, tail: => A)
lazy val x = new A(0, y)
lazy val y = new A(1, z)
lazy val z = new A(2, x)
```

Note that this does not work with *case* classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a by-name parameter.

```
class A(__a: => A, val b: Int) {
  def a = __a
  override def toString() = b.toString
}
object A {
  def apply(a: => A, b: Int) = new A(a, b)
}
```