# Lazy evaluation of values in sequence

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a bunch of lazy values:

```
lazy val v1: T = ... 
lazy val v2: T = ... 
lazy val v3: T = ...
```

And I have a boolean function which given a result of type `T`, checks whether it satisfies a certain criterion

```
def f(value: T): Boolean = { /* something here */ }
```

I want to find the value that satisfies a certain criterion, in a lazy fashion: like you keep evaluating things as you see them, and stop evaluating as soon as you find the first one that satisfies your condition: 
I tried this:

```
Iterable(v1, v2, v3).find(f)
```

But apparently this would trigger all the values `v1`, `v2`, `v3` (while I want them to be lazy). 
Is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because when you pass your `lazy val`s to a constructor, they are evaluated strictly, unless the constructor itself is *pass-by-name*.

For example, the `cons` notation of `Stream` (the lazy counterpart of `List`) allows you to achieve what you want:

```
lazy val v1 = { print("v1 "); 1 }
lazy val v2 = { print("v2 "); 2 }
lazy val v3 = { print("v3 "); 3 }

(v1 #:: v2 #:: v3 #:: Stream.empty).
  find(_ == 2).
  foreach(println) // prints "v1 v2 2"
```

[Here](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html) is an interesting reading on laziness and by-name parameters.

Comment: I wish the syntax was slightly cleaner tho.

Comment: Seconded. It would be nice if you could simply do `Stream(v1, v2, v3)`, unfortunately `Stream.apply` takes its arguments by value. Which at first sight is pretty normal considering that varargs can only be passed by value. But this could easily be worked around with an implicit class `Lazy` (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579272/whats-the-neatest-way-to-define-circular-lists-with-scala)